# SOLID Principle In Laravel with Repository Pattern

Tags: oop, laravel, design-patterns, dry, solid-principles

I have some confusion about use of Controller with Repository Pattern while maintaining SOLID Principle. Consider, I have two types of Quotations

1. Commercial Quotation
2. Private Quotation

And there is a high chance of new types of quotations in future. Each Quotations has different fields, business logics yet they share many common functions. So I created a QuotationInterface

**Quotation Inteface**

```php
interface QuotationInterface
{   
    public function save(array $data);

}
```

**Quotation class that implement the interface**

```php
class CommercialQuotation implements QuotationInterface
{   
    public function(array $data)
    {
        // save commercial quotation
    }
}

class PrivateQuotation implements QuotationInterface
{   
    public function(array $data)
    {
    // save Private quotation
    }
}
```

**Quotation Repository**

```php
class QuotationRepository 
{
    public function save(array $data, QuotationInterface $quotation)
    {
        $quotation->save($data);
    }
}
```

**QotationController**

```php
public function store(Resource $resource)
{

    $inputs = $resource->all();

    /**
    *  Clearly here Open/Close Principle is broken
    */

    if ($inputs['type'] == 'private'){
        $quotation = new PrivateQuotation;;
    }
    else if($inputs['type'] == 'commercial'){
        $quotation = new CommercialQuotation;
    }

    $this->repo->save($inputs, $quotation);
}
```

Here in my QuotationController, it is clearly violating Open/Close Principle..

Is it a good idea to Create a Controller for each type of quotation (*might be 10+ some day, who know?*) to avoid the OCP violation or my design is just wrong? Any suggestion, design change tips, resource are welcome.

NOTE: My Quotation Controller will have many other functions except the save only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going ahead the way you've shown, i suggest you to use a single controller for your quotations and use a **Factory** design pattern to create your `$quotation` objects

For example, with a simple factory like this:

```php
//FACTORY CLASS
abstract class QuotationFactory
{
    /** return QuotationInterface */
    public static function createQuotation($type)
    {
        switch($type)
        {
            CASE "private":
                return new PrivateQuotation();
            break;

            CASE "commercial":
                return new CommercialQuotation();
            break;    
        }
    }
}
```

you could use the factory from you controllers' methods:

```php
//YOUR CONTROLLER'S METHOD
public function store(Resource $resource)
{   
    $inputs = $resource->all();

    //delegate objects creation to factory class
    $quotation = QuotationFactory::createQuotation( $inputs['type'] );

    $this->repo->save($inputs, $quotation);
}
```

This way you are not going to violate the open/closed principle in your controllers, because as you add quotations, you'll only need to modify the method of the factory (adding cases to the switch statement ), and it will return a `QuotationFactory` object wherever needed.

This will also keep your code **DRY** and **SOLID** because you don't have to repeat the if/else statements to create your objects in your controller's methods as you delegate the responsability of the objects' creation to a specific factory class

As correctly pointed ount in the comments below, the Simple factory is going to help you avoiding the Open/Closed Principle in your controllers but be ware that, from a more general point of view, the Simple Factory itself is inherently violating the OCP as it uses a switch case.

Anyway, from what i see of your application, the Simple factory could be a good solution, as your primary concern is to build in many places instances from a variable type. Thus, using the Simple factory you can 'hide' this process of creating objects into the factory and get the instances you need in your controllers. So you are violating the OCP only inside the factory in the switch case, but i think this could be a beareble trade-off

Comment: I am going to follow your example. Thanks.

Comment: The need to modify the factory is a classic violation of the Open/Closed Principle: it means the code is not closed to modification. In fact, switch/case is always a violation of OCP, which is why it's not included in the GoF Factory Method design pattern. The design pattern is based on polymorphism.

Comment: @jaco0646: Design patterns are not absolute rules, but it's importat to adeguate them to the actual situation. In a case like this a simple factory could be a good solution. As i poined out in the end of my post, depending on the app's architecture the op could implement an abstract factory or a factory method

Comment: It's a good point that simple factories are extremely useful, in spite of the fact they violate OCP. However, the answer does not make that point clear by showing a simple factory and then claiming it does _not_ violate OCP. If the intention was to say that it's ok to violate OCP by using a simple factory in this case, then that's a valid point; but do note that OCP was a concern of the author, and this answer may mislead him into thinking that a simple factory complies with OCP, which it does not.

Comment: @jaco0646 : The primary concern of the OP was to not violate the OCP specifically in the controllers, but, from a more general point of view, what you're saying is true. i've edit my post to make things clearer

Answer (score 1):

I think this mostly depends on the scope of your application. In the PHP world these days, people are so angry with if/else statements :). However, if that works for your application and seems reasonable in the scope of YOUR context, I think that's fine.

Businesses change and Business changes aren't always easy to plan for. You can only try to make those changes easier when they arise.

That being said, classes are cheap and I think that having separate classes at this point (and in the future) is very reasonable.  If the requirements for each type of quotation expand, you'll be in good footing and I don't think you're abstracting so far that you're code will be difficult to understand.

Comment: Hmm.. I think you are right.. There are not any absolute correct answer of this question and what you said is logical. I need to try my best to stick with best practice but sometimes need to go offtrack due to application context.

Comment: This answer is so generic... couldn't it be copy-and-pasted to every PHP design patterns question on SO?

Comment: Generic or not, it's realistic. The fact is that you can't apply an absolute truth to this sort of question. Yes there's multiple ways to do things,  and no not all of them are applicable in every context.  And I think it's good to think about these sorts of questions, and moreover, realize that ones approach may differ in any given context.

Comment: Also, I acknowledged in my answer that his proposed solution is valid and reasonable. But one can't say it's the absolute best solution for his application without knowing the context of his application. And I believe that's an important idea to consider.

Comment: I think the problem here is the question itself. "_Is it a good idea to..._" is a [type of question to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) because, "_every answer is equally valid_". Without the necessary context to answer with absolute truth, this question is not a good fit for SO. It may be appropriate for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as a "software architecture and design" question.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but i hope my comment helps more people searching your issue.

You should follow the following principle:

"If you have a conditional like that you should do it in the low level abstraction not in the high level"

so the design should be:

```
class QuotationFactory
{   
    public static function make($type)
    {
        switch($type)
        {
            CASE "private":
                return new PrivateQuotation();
            CASE "commercial":
                return new CommercialQuotation();
            default:
                throw new InvalidTypeException("Invalid type code.");
        }
    }
}
```

The above refactoring called "Replace conditional/type code with polymorphism".

If there're no new types in the future you should follow "Replace Parameter with explicit methods" refactoring, it would improve the readability.

For more you should read a book called "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code" by Martin Fowler.